# Searching JSON with Javascript Kafka Magic Tool not returning result

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following Message in JSON format.  I am trying to do a Javascript search to find out of hundreds of these messages whether the EmailAddress matches a value I am searching for:

```
 "Message": {
          "Event": {
            "Type": "INFO",
            "IsSuccessful": true,
            "Details": {
              "Value": "{\"EmailAddress\":\"test@test.com\",\"SystemId\":\"5\"}"
            }
```

This is what I was trying:

```
function findItem(items) {
    
    if (!items) return console.log('failed');
    for (i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].Event.Details.Value.EmailAddress === "test@test.com\") return console.log('found');
    } 
    return console.log('fail 2');
}

return findItem(Context.Message);
```

Am I missing something - the search is not returning my console.log('found')

**UPDATE***
I should have clarified - this us using Kafka Magic Tool - [https://www.kafkamagic.com/usage/development/#:~:text=validating%20a%20producer.-,Use%20JavaScript%20queries%20to%20search%20for%20a%20message,fields%2C%20headers%2C%20and%20metadata](https://www.kafkamagic.com/usage/development/#:%7E:text=validating%20a%20producer.-,Use%20JavaScript%20queries%20to%20search%20for%20a%20message,fields%2C%20headers%2C%20and%20metadata).

Comment: `.Details.Value` is a string, you'll need to `JSON.parse()` it first

Comment: so like in the for loop - var detail = JSON.Parse(items[i].Event.Details.Value);  then the if can be if(detail.EmailAddress ===

Comment: @David - I updated - I should have clarified - this is using Kafka Magic Javascript search tool

Answer (score 0):

`items[i].Event.Details.Value` is encoded JSON, you'll need to [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it before you could access `.EmailAddress`.

Use something like the following:

```js
function findItem(items) {
    if (!items) return false;
    for (i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
        let parsedDetails = JSON.parse(items[i].Event.Details.Value);
        if (parsedDetails.EmailAddress === "test@test.com") {
            console.log('found', items[i]);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I made an update and included the link to the tool I am using - Kafka Magic - even with the update it doesnt work.  I am not sure it allows JSON.parse - it doesnt seem to even allow console.logging or debugger statement - which is annoying

Comment: Well it states that it has 'Full support for ECMAScript 5.1 standard', so JSON.parse should work fine. Did you see my latest edit with `return true` and `return false`? `return console.log()` won't work.

Comment: yeah - giving that a go - I see that its JavaScript search has to return a bool

Comment: still no luck :(

Comment: I got this working - d'oh - I didnt need a for loop - my Value is not an array - there is one on each message.  I did need the JSON parse though so thanks for this